# Extracting an unknown function from an integral with a known answer

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following function:

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}{l(x')K_L(x'-x)dx'}$

Where $f$ and $K_L$ are known functions. The parameters for $f$, $l$, and $K_L$ all range from 0 to 1. $l$ is my unknown function and I'm trying to isolate it and express it in terms of everything else here. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: $K_L$ must have a range larger than $[0,1]$; it must take values in $[-1,1]$. Are there any assumptions of continuity or the like on these functions?

Comment: Try looking up convolution, and in particular deconvolution.